# Log4j2 monitorInterval performance

Tags: java, performance, logging, log4j2

In log4j2, `monitorInterval` attribute is available for `Configuration` element. I tried to read about the performance impact of this attribute but couldn't find any source anywhere. So, I have multiple questions regarding `monitorInterval` attribute.

1. I would like to know, what performance impact it has by specifying a small value as `5` (5 seconds) and a large value let's say as `3000` (5 minutes) in `Configuration` element?
2. What exactly happens? Does that mean, it will automatically detect every time a specified interval of time has elapsed?
3. Is there any way to force log4j2 to reload configuration **right away** via configuration files (XML, JSON, YAML, PROPERTIES), not programmatic reconfiguration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It used to be the case that there was a small performance impact. Concretely, Log4j2 would occasionally check the `lastModified` time of the configuration file when processing a log event. It was clever enough not to do that on every event but only when enough time had passed since the last time it checked: only once every `monitorInterval` seconds.

Since Log4j 2.5 it is different: there's a watcher background thread that occasionally wakes up and checks the `lastModified` time of the configuration file. So now there's no impact on logging performance. (The reason for this change was actually not performance but accuracy: previously files would not roll over if until a something was logged, which could be much later than the rollover time.) See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1202 for details.

To force a configuration reload, apart from touching the configuration file and programmatic reconfiguration, you can use the JMX interface. Also take a look at the [Configurator](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configurator.html) class in log4j-core. It has several methods that result in reconfiguration.

Comment: so the 30 seconds in the manual is really overkill? I could set it to 3 or 5 without issues?